# Downloading all files from URL with extension filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to download all files from FTP or HTTP using extension filter 
For example, I have one URL that contains many MKV files and I want to set the extension filtering to download all MKV files from URL or download all jpg

I can use open-Uri for this but this method only download one file and save it

```
require 'open-uri'
download = open('https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/video/caring_for_your_kitten_video/650x350_caring_for_your_kitten_video.jpg')
IO.copy_stream(download, '650x350_caring_for_your_kitten_video.png')
```

Comment: Create a code block highlighting your code and clicking the `{}` button in the toolbar. Single backticks are for single-line code samples only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to get all links and put it to a text file
Then using system command to get a text file to download by the download manager, for example, I need to get mkv links from URL pages

```
    require 'mechanize'
    mechanize = Mechanize.new
    page = mechanize.get("URL")
    page.search('a').each do |link|
    uri = mechanize.resolve(' ' + link).to_s
    if uri.include?(".mkv")
    File.open("url.txt", "a") do |file|
     file.puts uri
        end
      end
    end
    puts "The File has been created!"
    #exec 'idman /d URL'
    #puts "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a limitation on the server site. If your server doesn't allow directory listing (which most of the time HTTP servers dont) there is not a lot you can do.

So to answer your question: `open-uri` will not allow you to list files.

As for FTP. you are able to list all files in a directory [like this](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Net/FTP.html#method-i-nlst). Not sure if you're able to pass in wildcards. If not you will have to use the [select method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to filter on the filenames you want.